# Using AJAX with CodeIgniter to update field in database upon clicking in a checkbox

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Long ago I wrote a web-based recipe management program. It is written using CodeIgniter(2). Recipes are shown in a list view when searching or browsing, and can be brought up in an edit view where fields can be entered/changed. I wanted to be able to edit some recipe info while in the list view without needing to open up the editor window, make changes, and click Submit. These changes are just setting or unsetting a checkbox. The recipes have certain attributes such as being "New", or marked for "Export", and these attributes are shown as check boxes that a properly authenticated user can manipulate.

I found some code examples of how to implement a simple AJAX routine to do this. And, it worked fine until recently when I updated CodeIgnitor the the last version 3.x release.

I could really use some help to figure out how to get this working again. And, perhaps even integrate the database call into my CodeIgnitor-based model rather than as a standalone php script outside the CodeIgnitor framework. And, since I am way out of date on coding skills and keeping up with technology like JSON, AJAX, etc. I'd appreciate specific help that is not too abstracted from my specific need. ;-) I've seen other posts asking for similar help, but was not able to figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Here is what I have today that no longer works. This is the script added to the HTML header on the pages where I want this functionality:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--  
function chkit(row, chk, field) {

   chk = (chk==true ? "1" : "0");
   var url = "http://localhost/recipes/check_validate.php?number="+row+"&chkYesNo="+chk+"&field="+field;

   if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   // Use get instead of post.
   req.open("GET", url, true);
   req.send(null);
}
//-->
</script>
```

Each listed recipe has a few checkboxes associated with it as described above. Each checkbox ends up with source code that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="f_attribute6_1052" value="0"   onclick="chkit(1052, this.checked, 'attribute6');" />
```

So, as I understand it, when a checkbox is clicked either on or off, the "chkit" javascript function is called and is passed the recipe number (1052 in this case), the status of the checkbox (true or false), and the name of the attribute field, in this case "attribute6".

That script runs a php script called 'check_validate.php'. And, here is the code for that:

```
<?php
// Would be nice to generalize this, even integrate with the recipe model code
$dbhost = 'localhost';   // usually localhost
$dbuser = 'username';      // database username
$dbpass = 'password';      // database password

$db = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Database connection failed.");

mysql_select_db('recipe_db');

// Get the variables.
$number = $_GET['number'];
$value = $_GET['chkYesNo'];
$field = $_GET['field'];

$sql = "UPDATE recipes SET $field = $value WHERE recipeNumber=$number";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Now, I know there is an immediate problem. Since I am not abstracting these DB calls and using mysql directly, something needs to change to use mysqli instead.

What would be nice is to move this last php script into a function in my model code to get rid of the non-CodeIgnitor php script. And, I understand that the javascript I'm using in my HTML header is very old, obsolete and not secure.

Remember, I'm not really a trained coder and need handholding here ;-)

Comment: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the check_validate.php to this:

```
<?php
// Would be nice to generalize this, even integrate with the recipe model code
$dbhost = 'localhost';      // usually localhost, this mimics what is in the database config file
$dbuser = 'user';       // database username
$dbpass = 'pass';   // database password
$dbname = 'recipes';        // database name

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: ' . $db->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$number = $_GET['number'];
$value = $_GET['chkYesNo'];
$field = $_GET['field'];

$sql = "UPDATE recipes SET $field = $value WHERE recipeNumber=$number";

$rs=$db->query($sql);

if($rs === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $db->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
}

?>
```

And, it works. I'm still getting some Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors in my js console, so need to track that down. But, functionality is restored and the code works as it used to. So, the solution was just a proper implementation of mysqli instead of mysql.